# Errors with Keras/Tensorflow on Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I successfully installed keras/tensorflow. I have windows 10 and Python 3.7.4. However, when executing the following code, I get a long list of errors. I searched Google and many other sites about this. There are a few questions here that resembled the same issue, I tried the solutions to those questions, but I am still getting these errors. I uninstalled and reinstalled Keras/tensorflow. Still no change. Can anyone give me some insight to how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code and FULL error trace as text not image.

Comment: Most of the examples, where a model is built for Tensorflow 2 with Keras, use tensorflow.keras in the imports. Have you tried this or is not sufficient for your use of Keras?